# command output > sed replace after a particular string

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, centos

Hello I am trying to insert the output of command output > sed replace after a particular string in a file as part of user data on machine boot up

```
[centos@ip-192-168-2-22 scylla]$ sudo sed -i.bak 's/broadcast_rpc_address: : /broadcast_rpc_address:\/$hostname -i | awk '{print $2}'/' /etc/scylla/scylla.yaml
```

file is currently

```
broadcast_rpc_address:
```

replace with

```
broadcast_rpc_address: (the ip of the machine)
```

Comment: You can't insert with shell redirection. Only overwrite or append.

Comment: what do you want to replace in `scylla.yml` ?

Comment: replace ' broadcast_rpc_address:   with ' broadcast_rpc_address: output of command

Comment: What should go where? What is your question? What have you tried? What is the output of the command? "go after" means on the next line, after a space or right after? Please post example input (ie. state of the file before change) and example output (ie. state of the file after change).

Comment: I thought this should work

 sudo sed -i.bak 's/broadcast_rpc_address: : /broadcast_rpc_address:\/$hostname -i | awk '{print $2}'/' /etc/scylla/scylla.yaml

Comment: `sed -i "s/broadcast_rpc_address:/& $(hostname -i)/" scylla.yaml` (may require GNU sed)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
sed -i.bak "s/broadcast_rpc_address:/broadcast_rpc_address: $(hostname -i)/" /etc/scylla/scylla.yaml
```

This will replace `broadcast_rpc_address:` by `broadcast_rpc_address: $(hostname -i)`. Now, because this string is in double quotes - not single quotes - this tells the shell to interpret some magic sequences inside the string. In particular `$(somecommand)` means to run somecommand and insert its output into the string. Of course, change "hostname -i" in the command I gave above to anything else you want (it can even be an entire pipeline.

Your original attempt used something that started with `$hostname`. This syntax, `$hostname`, doesn't run the command `hostname`, but rather looks for a variable called `hostname`, which isn't what you wanted. You need the `$(...)` syntax instead. Your original attempt also had problems with nested quotes, which don't work.